# Redux lose firebase user when reloading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux

I'm trying to make a messenger web app using react, redux, and firebase.

I already did something very similar using the context from react but now I need to learn redux so here I am.

I've been able to build the Login/Signup pages and actions, so I can signup and login with firebase auth and load the dashboard once logged in (while keeping it private if not logged in).

The problem is when I log in everything is ok, the dashboard load, cool.
BUT if I reload the page, Redux lose the 'user' state, however, I don't get redirected to the login page, it just stays there in the dashboard without a state or anything.

Of course, it would be cool if I could just reload the page and keep the user information stored instead of losing everything every reload.

this is the code:

Private Route

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import{ useSelector } from 'react-redux' 

export default function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest}) {
    const  currentUser  = useSelector(state=>state.auth.user)
    
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render = {props => {
                return currentUser ? <Component {...props}/> : <Redirect to = "/login" />
            }}
        >

        </Route>
    )
}
```

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import SignUp from './components/auth/Signup'
import Login from './components/auth/Login'
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard'
import PrivateRoute from './components/PrivateRoute'

const App = () => {

  return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <PrivateRoute exact path ="/" component = {Dashboard}/>
          <Route path = "/signup" component = {SignUp} />
          <Route path = "/login" component = {Login} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
  );
}


export default App;
```

authReducers

```
import { LOGIN, SIGNUP, LOGOUT } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    user: {}
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type){
        case LOGIN:
            return{
                ...state,
                user: action.payload
            }
        case LOGOUT:
            return{
                ...state,
                user: action.payload
            }
        case SIGNUP:
            return{
                ...state,
                user: action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

auth actions

```
import { LOGIN, LOGOUT, SIGNUP } from './types';
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/database"
import { auth } from '../firebase'

//azioni per login-logout-signup
//restituiscono il current user (ad eccezione del logout)
export const login = loginData => dispatch => {
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(loginData.email, loginData.password)
    .then(user => dispatch({
        type: LOGIN,
        payload: user
    }))
}


export const logout = () => dispatch => {
    auth.signOut().then(dispatch({
        type: LOGOUT,
        payload: {}
    }))
}


export const signup = signupData => dispatch => {
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(signupData.email, signupData.password).then((data)=>{
        firebase.database().ref('users/' + data.user.uid).set({
            username: signupData.username,
        })
    }).then(user => dispatch(
        {
            type: SIGNUP,
            payload: user
        }
    ))
}
```

dashboard

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Dashboard() {
    return (
        <div>
            we
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: you can use localstorage

Comment: or persist the redux state with a library called redux-persist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code only handles the case when the user actively signs in, so when they click a sign-up or sign-in button in your app.

When you reload the page however, Firebase restores the authentication state without the user clicking such a button - and without your code calling `signInWithEmailAndPassword`. This is because the Firebase SDK keeps the authentication credentials for the user in local storage, and refreshes their sign-in state when it loads.

This requires a call to the server however, which means you'll need an auth state listener to capture the state as shown in the Firebase documentation on [getting the currently signed in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users):

> ```
> firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
>  if (user) {
>    // User is signed in.
>  } else {
>    // No user is signed in.
>  }
> });
> ```

When you use this code, it get executed twice upon a page reload. Once right away with the user being `null`, and then once more later once the user's sign-in state has been restored.